# iOS - CAKeyFrameAnimation - Not Playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uiview

I have looked at a few guides for CAKeyFrameAnimation and I am failing to see how to trigger them. The only thing I can think of is that I have to use it as a return, but that doesn't make much sense to me.

-H File-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ImageSequenceViewController : UIViewController 
          <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer;


 NSMutableArray *myImages;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *bView;
 IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

-(IBAction)takeLeftSwipeRecognitionEnabledFrom:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl;

-(IBAction)ButtonPressed1: (id)sender;

@end
```

-M File-

```
#import "ImageSequenceViewController.h"

@implementation ImageSequenceViewController

@synthesize swipeLeftRecognizer;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize segmentedControl;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

//CUSTOM CODE
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

-(void)loadLeft {
 //aView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];

 [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
          0.0,
          [[self view] frame].size.height,
          [[self view] frame].size.width)];

 myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for(NSUInteger count=0; count<100; count++){
  NSString *fileName;

  if (count < 10) 
  {
   fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"trailerRotation_000%d", count];
  } 
  else if (10 <= count < 100) 
  {
   fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"trailerRotation_00%d", count];
  }
  else 
  {
   fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"trailerRotation_0%d", count];
  }

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"jpg"];

  //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
  //[myImages addObject:image];

  [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
 }

 CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"Contents"];
 [anim setDuration:0.10];
 [anim setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationDiscrete];
 [anim setRepeatCount:1];
 [anim setValues:myImages];

 [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
 [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"images"];

 //aView.animationImages = myImages;
 //aView.animationDuration = 10.00;
 //aView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

}

-(void)loadRight {
 bView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for(NSUInteger count=99; count>0; count--){
  NSString *countString;

  if (count < 10) 
  {
   countString = @"000";
   countString = [countString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", count];
  } 
  else if (10 <= count < 100) 
  {
   countString = @"00";
   countString = [countString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", count];
  } 
  else if (100 <= count < 1000)
  {
   countString = @"00";
   countString = [countString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", count];
  }

  NSLog(@"%d", count);

  NSString *fileName = @"trailerRotation_";
  fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingFormat:countString];
  fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];

  [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
 }

 bView.animationImages = myImages; 
 bView.animationDuration = 10.00;
 bView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trailerRotation_0000.jpg"]];
 //[self.view addSubview:imageView];


 [self loadLeft];
 [self loadRight];

 UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

 recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
 [recognizer release];

 recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
 self.swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer;
 swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

 if ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
 }

 self.swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer;
 [recognizer release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

 self.segmentedControl = nil;
 self.swipeLeftRecognizer = nil;
 self.imageView = nil;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)startItLeft {
 NSLog(@"Left");

 //[aView startAnimating];
 //[self.view addSubview:aView];
 //[aView release];
 [bView release];
}

-(void)startItRight {
 NSLog(@"Right");

 [bView startAnimating];
 [self.view addSubview:bView];
 //[aView release];
 [bView release];
}

//- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//}

//- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//}

//- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
//}

-(IBAction)ButtonPressed1:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"Button");

 //[aView stopAnimating];
 [bView stopAnimating];
 //[self loadLeft];
 [self loadRight];
}

-(IBAction)takeLeftSwipeRecognitionEnabledFrom:(UISegmentedControl *) aSegmentControl {

 if ([aSegmentControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
 }
 else {
  [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
 }
}

-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

 //CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
 //[self showImageWithText:@"swipe" atPoint:location];

 if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
  //[self startItLeft];
 }
 else {
  [self startItRight]; 
 }
}
//CUSTOM CODE



// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I'm rather new to iOS development so any advice is helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: My advice: don't post code that isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: If I knew where the flaw in my code was I would... but it complies and runs with out any console error or other indication.

Comment: FYI, your layer created in `-loadLeft` has the wrong size. You flipped the order of the width/height parameters.

Comment: I don't believe so, I managed to get the code working by pasting it into a new project file in chunks... I loose most of the image when I flop those numbers. Could it have some thing to do with the orientation of the image I'm using?

Comment: *lose not Loose. Image is 1024 x 768 and not 768 x 1024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit it was a PEBKAC error.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
[myImages addObject:(id)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path].CGImage];
```

Since the `CAKeyFrameAnimation` expects `CGImageRef` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load up 100 images and cycle them all within the space of 0.1 second. Not only is that pretty ridiculous (that's 1000fps right there, and CoreAnimation is capped at 60fps), but it's likely to take longer than 0.1 seconds for CoreAnimation to copy all the images before it even starts, which means that it will have finished before it started (and therefore no animation will occur).

Comment: The speed at which it is playing doesn't appear to be a factor in it's problems... I've set it from the 0.1 to 100 and it still stalls out on a black screen with no error in the console.

Comment: You're using the key path `@"Contents"`. Try `@"contents"`.